# Factoring after polynomial long division

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation, education

I have gotten the code to do polynomial long division, but I want my students to also factor the solution if possible.[image]

Comment: Could you clarify what your question is exactly? Also, please post code rather than images.

Comment: The solution x^2+7x+10 can be factored further, is there a way to add code so that the final solution is in simplest/factored form.

Comment: With Mathematica or Wolfram Alpha?

Answer (score 2):

```
poly1 = (x^3 + 3 x^2 - 18 x - 40);
poly2 = (x - 4);

query = "polynomial long division (" <> ToString[poly1, InputForm] <> 
  ")/(" <> ToString[poly2, InputForm] <> ")";

WolframAlpha[query, {{"QuotientAndRemainder"}, "Content"}, 
 PodStates -> {"QuotientAndRemainder__Step-by-step solution"}]
```

[image]

```
(quotient = poly1/poly2 // Simplify) // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
(quotient // Factor) // TraditionalForm
```

[image]